# CFN-Lint error in nested Cloudformation stack

Tags: amazon-web-services, gitlab, aws-cloudformation, lint

I am creating AWS resources using CloudFormation Nested Stack and the pipeline runs in Gitlab.

```
Resources:
  CF-resource:
    Type: AWS::CloudFormation::Stack
    Properties:
      TemplateURL: local path of yaml file 
      Parameters:
```

when Using CFN-Lint test on parent stack I am getting below error.

** W3002 This code may only work with `package` cli command as the property (/TemplateURL) is a string**

Can you help me to solve this

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning to let you know you can't deploy this template directly without first packaging it. You can suppress it by adding `-i W3002`.

Comment: What would be the alternative, recommended way, to using `TemplateURL` ? This seems to be related to [github: cfn-lint/#1683](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/cfn-lint/issues/1683)